# .htaccess - Redirect with the following rules / conditions?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How would a rule matching the following look like:

Redirect all non-file requests to root (example.com/foo or example.com/foo/goo to example.com)
Redirect all non-existing file requests to root (example.com/not_exisiting_file.php to example.com)
Pass all requests to existing files.

How would a mod-rewrite in htaccess look like?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Apache 2.4, see if the `FallbackResource` directive will do what you want.

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource

It is intended to supersede the previous use of a `RewriteCond` with `-d` and `-f`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule in your `/.htaccess` file to redirect all non-existing file requests to the root:

```bsh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/ [R,NC,L]
```